# Can anyone figure out how to extend this software divide routine to have a 16-bit quotient

Tags: c, assembly

Background...

I am currently trying to extend an assembly routine for an MCS-48 (which has no hardware divide) from the current 8-bit quotient, to a 16-bit quotient

This is a scan of the original routine here: http://techmattmillman.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/isisdiv.png

(yes, that is from a dot-matrix printer). I have faithfully translated it to 'C' code, and have verified that it works the same as the original:

```
uint8_t mcs48_divide(uint16_t dividend, uint8_t divisor, uint8_t *remainder)
{
    if ((dividend >> 8) >= divisor)
        goto mcs48_div_exit; // Impossible. Result would overflow. Bail.

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) // One pass for each bit of result
    {
        uint8_t msb;
        uint8_t bit15_was_set = 0;

        if (dividend & 0x8000)
            bit15_was_set = 1; // Note if this was set, can't check if after shift.

        dividend <<= 1; // Next bit

        msb = (dividend >> 8);
        if (msb >= divisor || bit15_was_set)
        {
            // Subtract remainder from MSB, preserve and increment quotient
            dividend = (((msb - divisor) << 8) | (dividend & 0xFF)) + 1;
        }
    }

mcs48_div_exit:
    *remainder = (dividend >> 8);
    return (dividend & 0xFF);
}
```

It returns the 8-bit quotient. If I could just figure out how to modify the 'C' version of this, I could re-do the assembly routine, but I haven't even managed to figure that out :(

Comment: What have you tried? A minimalist approach would be to change `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`, `uint16_t` to `uint32_t`, bit 15 to bit 31, `0x8000` to `0x80000000u`, `0xff` to `0xffff`, `8` to `16`, etc, etc.

Comment: I've made several attempts. It doesn't seem to be that simple.

Comment: It seems to work here. Can you point out some failing test vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a simple bit-wise longhand binary division, the minimalist approach would be to change `uint8_t` to `uint16_t`, `uint16_t` to `uint32_t`, bit 15 to bit 31, `0x8000` to `0x80000000u`, `0xff` to `0xffff`, 8 to 16, and so on.

When I do that, the resulting code seems to work correctly, although an exhaustive test would take a few days from what I can see, so in the "smoke" test below I am using random test vectors.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define USE_RANDOM_TEST (1)

uint16_t mcs48_divide_ext (uint32_t dividend, uint16_t divisor, uint16_t *remainder)
{
    if ((dividend >> 16) >= divisor)
        goto mcs48_div_ext_exit; // Impossible. Result would overflow. Bail.

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) // One pass for each bit of result
    {
        uint16_t msb;
        uint16_t bit31_was_set = 0;

        if (dividend & 0x80000000u)
            bit31_was_set = 1; // Note if this was set, can't check if after shift.

        dividend <<= 1; // Next bit

        msb = (dividend >> 16);
        if (msb >= divisor || bit31_was_set)
        {
            // Subtract remainder from MSB, preserve and increment quotient
            dividend = (((msb - divisor) << 16) | (dividend & 0xFFFF)) + 1;
        }
    }

mcs48_div_ext_exit:
    *remainder = (dividend >> 16);
    return (dividend & 0xFFFF);
}

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
unsigned int z=362436069,w=521288629,jsr=362436069,jcong=123456789;
#define znew (z=36969*(z&0xffff)+(z>>16))
#define wnew (w=18000*(w&0xffff)+(w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (jsr^=(jsr<<13),jsr^=(jsr>>17),jsr^=(jsr<<5)) /* 2^32-1 */
#define CONG (jcong=69069*jcong+13579)                     /* 2^32 */
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t dividend;
    uint16_t divisor, quot, rem, quot_ref, rem_ref;
    
    dividend = 0;
    do {
        divisor = 0;
        do {
            quot = mcs48_divide_ext (dividend, divisor, &rem);
            if ((dividend >> 16) >= divisor) {
                rem_ref = dividend >> 16;
                quot_ref = dividend & 0xFFFF;
            } else {
                quot_ref = dividend / divisor;
                rem_ref = dividend - quot_ref * divisor;
            }
            if ((quot != quot_ref) || (rem != rem_ref)) {
                printf ("!!!! dividend=%08x  divisor=%04x  quot=%04x  rem=%04x  quot_ref=%04x  rem_ref=%04x\n",
                        dividend, divisor, quot, rem, quot_ref, rem_ref);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
#if USE_RANDOM_TEST
            divisor = KISS & 0xffff;
#else // USE_RANDOM_TEST
            divisor++;
#endif // USE_RANDOM_TEST
        } while (divisor);
#if USE_RANDOM_TEST
        dividend = KISS;
#else // USE_RANDOM_TEST
        dividend++;
#endif // USE_RANDOM_TEST
        if ((dividend & 0xff) == 0) printf ("\rdividend=%08x", dividend);
    } while (dividend);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

OP clarified in comments that they need a 16-bit divisor but want to retain the 16-bit dividend. This does not really change the algorithm. The 32-bit accumulator is still required. The 16-bit dividend is initially placed in the least significant 16 bits of the accumulator and the most significant 16 bits are cleared. The subtractions for the long-hand division are performed on the upper half (most significant 16 bits) of the accumulator, and in each step the next dividend bit is moved from the lower half to the upper half as the entire 32-bit accumulator is shifted left by one bit.

In 8-bit microprocessors of the 1980s the 32-bit accumulator had to be constructed from four 8-bit registers. On the Z80 the arrangement `H:L:A:C` was commonly used, with `D:E` holding the divisor and `B` the loop counter.

The C version of the 16/16->16 bit unsigned integer division looks a shown below. This version can easily be tested exhaustively in a few minutes on modern PC hardware.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t mcs48_divide_ext (uint16_t dividend, uint16_t divisor, uint16_t *remainder)
{
    uint32_t accumulator = dividend; // Zero extend dividend

    if (0 >= divisor)
        goto mcs48_div_ext_exit; // Impossible. Result would overflow. Bail.

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) // One pass for each bit of result
    {
        uint16_t msb;
        uint8_t bit31_was_set = 0;

        if (accumulator & 0x80000000u)
            bit31_was_set = 1; // Note if this was set, can't check if after shift.

        accumulator <<= 1; // Next bit

        msb = (accumulator >> 16);
        if (msb >= divisor || bit31_was_set)
        {
            // Subtract remainder from MSB, preserve and increment quotient
            accumulator = (((msb - divisor) << 16) | (accumulator & 0xFFFF)) + 1;
        }
    }

mcs48_div_ext_exit:
    *remainder = (accumulator >> 16);
    return (accumulator & 0xFFFF);
}

int main (void)
{
    uint16_t dividend, divisor, quot, rem, quot_ref, rem_ref;
    
    dividend = 0;
    do {
        divisor = 0;
        do {
            quot = mcs48_divide_ext (dividend, divisor, &rem);
            if (0 >= divisor) {
                rem_ref = 0;
                quot_ref = dividend;
            } else {
                quot_ref = dividend / divisor;
                rem_ref = dividend - quot_ref * divisor;
            }
            if ((quot != quot_ref) || (rem != rem_ref)) {
                printf ("!!!! dividend=%08x  divisor=%04x  quot=%04x  rem=%04x  quot_ref=%04x  rem_ref=%04x\n",
                        dividend, divisor, quot, rem, quot_ref, rem_ref);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            divisor++;
        } while (divisor);
        dividend++;
        if ((dividend & 0xff) == 0) printf ("\rdividend=%04x", dividend);
    } while (dividend);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @Matthew Millman I don't know how close the MCS-48 instruction set architecture is to the 8080, but I expect this to be a tight fit for the available registers. Looking at a published 16-bit division routine, I see the 32-bit "dividend" accumulator represented by H:L:A:C (in the end H:L holds the remainder and A:C the quotient), the 16-bit divisor by D:E, and the loop counter by B. So all general purpose registers are used.

Comment: I expected that the pseudo C code would probably end up using a 32 bit dividend. When converted back to MCS-48 assembler, more likely is that a 24-bits would be used (3 8-bit registers), MCS-48 has 8 GPR's available so not an issue, however in my implementation (https://github.com/inaxeon/mcs48temp/blob/master/main.asm) things are tight, so probably will need a re-work to accomodate.

Comment: It is interesting to see this with some test code, but in this example, all integer sizes are doubled. I only needed the quotient increased. Not something I'd be able to take back to the original implementation.

Comment: @MatthewMillman When the dividend is 16-bit only, the algorithm stays the same, except that initially the upper 16 bits of the 32-bit accumulator are set to zero and the lower 16 bits of the 32-bit accumulator are set to the dividend. This is how we did it back in the 1980s (both by my recollection and by consulting a book with canned Z80 routines). I will rework the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Will mark your answer as correct, because it told me what I was missing: All of the arithmetic has to be 16-bit for it to work. I was trying to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer provided by njuffa, and that fantastic bit of test code, I'd come out with something like this:

```
uint16_t mcs48_div16(uint16_t dividend, uint8_t divisor, uint8_t *remainder)
{
    uint32_t accumulator = dividend;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) // One pass for each bit of result
    {
        uint8_t msb;
        uint8_t bit24_was_set = 0;

        if (accumulator & 0x800000)
            bit24_was_set = 1; // Note if this was set can't check if after shift.

        accumulator <<= 1; // Next bit
        accumulator &= 0xFFFFFF; // Simulate 24 bit type

        msb = (accumulator >> 16);
        if (msb >= divisor || bit24_was_set)
        {
            // Subtract remainder from MSB, preserve and increment quotient
            accumulator = (((msb - divisor) << 16) | (accumulator & 0xFFFF)) + 1;
        }
    }

mcs48_div_ext_exit:
    *remainder = (accumulator >> 16);
    return (accumulator & 0xFFFF);
}
```

Does the job, using the least resources possible. All that extra 16-bit arithmetic is going to make it a chore to translate back to MCS-48 assembler...